# Stringifying all array content with .map function

Tags: javascript

Why is this not working?

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var stringifiedNumbers = numbers.map(function(x) { 
   JSON.stringify(x);
})
console.log(stringifiedNumbers);
```

Why is my output:

> Array [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
>   undefined, undefined, undefined ]

Comment: Also seems total overkill to use `JSON.stringify` for a simple numeric. Just use `return x.toString()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not returning the stringified content so the function transforms the array into `undefined`s. [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) transforms each array element based on *the return value of the passed callback* and since yours returns nothing it transforms them to `undefined`:

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var stringifiedNumbers = numbers.map(function(x) {
  return JSON.stringify(x);
})
console.log(stringifiedNumbers);
```

You could shorten this with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
var stringifiedNumbers = numbers.map(x => JSON.stringify(x));
```

Because you are only using one return statement in the example above, you can implicitly return the expression with an arrow function. You could even just shorten it to:

```
numbers.map(JSON.stringify);
```

As it implicitly passes the argument and gets rid of the variable.